# Catching Signals c++

Tags: c++, threadpool, signals, handle

I have a boost threadpool which I use to do certain tasks. I also have a Sensor class that has the pure virtual function `doWork(int total) = 0;`. Whenever it is requested, my main process gets the necessary Sensor pointer and tells the threadpool to run `Sensor::doWork(int total)`.

```
threadpool->schedule(boost::bind(&Sensor::doWork,this,123456));
```

I am dynamically loading libraries of type Sensor, thus it is out of my control if someone else has faulty coding which results in SEGFAULTS and such. So is there a way for me to (in my main process) handle any errors thrown by `Sensor::doWork(int total)`, clean up the thread, delete that sensor object and notify the console what and where the error has occurred?

Comment: "Catching signals" is something different from "recovering from a segfault". The former is possible, the latter isn't.

Comment: So is there a way to catch the signals, rather than having the dynamic library throw a segfault?

Comment: You can catch signals with the standard `<signal>` C library. But that's not so important. What matters is the causality: The segfault *causes* the signal. But the signal cannot *prevent* the segfault (short of by going back in time).

Comment: I should just build a time machine is what you are saying?

But realistically, there is no way to catch the signal, delete the Sensor object which caused it, and move on?

Comment: You can catch the signal, but you cannot move on. There's *no way* to recover from *after* the segfault has happened. Your program is no longer in a well-defined state, so there is no way to recover meaningful operation. The SIGSEGV will be raised over and over again until you `terminate()`.

Comment: OK thanks, I guess I have to make sure the dynamic libraries being loaded do not have any issues...

Answer (score 2):

Really the only way to handle a segmentation fault here is to run `Sensor::doWork` in a completely separate *process*.

In UNIX, this involves using `fork` (or some other similar means), running `Sensor::doWork` in the child process, and then somehow shuttling the results back to the parent process.

I assume similar means are available in Windows.

EDIT: I thought I'd flesh out a bit some of the things you can do.

Solution #1: you can work with processes in the same fashion as you would threads. For example, you could create process pool that sit there in a loop of

- Wait for a task to be passed in over a pipe or queue or some similar object
- Perform the task
- Return the results over a pipe or queue or some similar object

And since you're executing the tasks in the other processes, you're protected against them crashing. The main difficulty with this solution is actually communicating between processes; maybe boost's interprocess library will help with that. I've mainly done this sort of thing in python, which has a standard `multiprocessing` module that handles this stuff for you.

Solution #2: You could divide your application into "safe" and "risky" portions that run in different processes. The "risky" portion executes the `Sensor::doWork` methods and anything else you might want to do in that process -- but only work that is acceptable to be spontaneously lost if it crashes. The "safe" portion deals with any precious information that you cannot afford to lose, and monitors the "risky" portion, performing some recovery operations when the child crashes. And, of course, whatever other work you decide you want to do in the safe part.

Comment: So is there a way to do this in a pool, so that I am not constantly setting up child processes, and waiting for them to finish? This is a time sensitive issue, so I feel that it would be time consuming to do so.

Comment: Don't guess that it's too slow -- actually try it out. And you could even set it up so you just have one child process and keep reusing it so long as it doesn't crash. But anyways, you seem to be very concerned about the `doWork` calls corrupting your process.

Comment: That aside, I think the question you are really asking is how to protect your process from being corrupted by the `doWork` calls. Running `doWork` in a separate process, I think, is the only reasonable way to provide that protection. Segmentation faults, incidentally, are usually *symptoms* of some sort of corruption. Even if you catch it, your program is still likely to be corrupted.

Comment: it looks like the multiprocess is the way to go. I will try to implement solution 1 first, and will update once I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you got a `SIGSEGV`, even if you caught it you have no guarantee about your program state so there's pretty much no way to recover.

If you're working with 3rd party libraries, and they're buggy, and the library maintainer won't fix it (and you don't have the source) then your only recourse is to run the third party library from within a totally separate binary that talks to the main binary by some means. See for example firefox and plugin-container.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to register a function callback to catch `SIGSEV`. In C this can be done using [signal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/csignal/signal/). Be aware, however, there is not much you can do, when the OS sends you a `SIGSEV` (note that it isn't required to). You don't really know in what state your program is in, I'd guess. If for example the heap got corrupt, new and delete operations may fail, so even a plain simple

```
 std::cout << std::string("hello world") << std::endl;
```

statement, might not work since memory from the heap needs to be allocated.

Best, Christoph

Comment: That is what I have now, but I was hoping there was some way to gracefully kill that thread and delete the Sensor object.